Laravel singleton - how to have just one instance
Try to get real Laravel singleton:

Service class:

<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class SingleTest
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $var
    ) {
        Log::info('init instance');
    }
}


Register this service as singleton:

<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\SingleTest;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton(SingleTest::class, fn() => new SingleTest('test singleton'));
    }
}


My routes for checking (web.php):

Route::get('/test1', fn() => app(SingleTest::class)->var);
Route::get('/test2', fn() => app(SingleTest::class)->var);

Then I curl /test1 and /test2 routes:

curl prints test singleton twice - good.
with log I expect that constructor called only once and init instance appears once. No, I see 2 messages which means that second instance of SingleTest also created. It's not a singleton.


PHP is a "Shared Nothing Architecture", singletons don't persist across HTTP requests since the app is booted fresh on every request.
You can use Laravel Octane if you want to persist them between requests, since it boots your app once (per worker), allowing multiple requests to share the same singleton until the worker gets reset or garbage collected.
